# Is it bad practice to appoint someone to a position without opening applications?

Tags: hiring-process

I have recently been appointed the editor of a publication. I am certain that a certain candidate will be the best person to become deputy editor. She is currently the assistant editor of the publication, has by far the most hands-on experience and has the best journalistic skill set. There is absolutely no way that she will be beaten by any other candidate who may apply.

However, the editorial board of the publication changes from year to year, and typically each position is opened up to an application process. I often find it quite banal, because there are often very obviously candidates that are the best for the position, yet they have to go through the rigmarole of filling in extensive applications and sitting through arduous interviews.

What is typically done in the business world? Can a CEO appoint a COO without much hassle? Are publications different? Is this publication different?

What is considered bad practice when it comes to hiring?

Comment: You can make it appear like your hiring process is more open by advertising every role. But you've made your mind up so you would be wasting people's time. A lot of organisations (governments) do this to be more ethical in some way. I think it's the opposite.

Comment: There's the "business world" and then there's the publicly traded and regulated companies that have CEOs and COOs who have a board of directors to account to. Their appointments may get a rubber stamp of approval, but they usually go through the entire hiring process. You could be dealing with some equal opportunity hiring issues if you don't open up the position.

Answer (score 4):

Hiring practices can vary widely between companies and organizations, and (at least in the U.S.), almost anything goes as long as the practice doesn't fall into discriminating based on prohibited categories such as race, religion, national origin, sexual orientation, non-job-impacting disabilities, etc.

That being said, a C-Level executive usually requires approval by the organization's board of directors.  If you are the editor, you should ask your publisher what the approved hiring process is, and follow it to the letter.

Edit - After your comment.  Internal promotions are certainly common enough.  Usually the application process is a mandate of the organization.  If yours has no such mandate, there's no reason to follow it if you don't want to.  However, given our currently litigious mindset, you should be very thorough in documenting your objective reasons for the promotion if there are any other potential candidates.  You probably want to get at least one "sign-off" on the promotion from the publisher beforehand, if possible.

My opinion only.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: The editor has complete discretion in terms of setting the hiring process – which is why I'm trying to figure out what the done thing is generally.

Answer (score 1):

As Wesley mentioned this largely depends on your organizational structure and practice.

I have never held a permanent position at a publisher, however I can tell you from working in various other industries that hiring practices can go from rubber stamp, to 3 month process (personally, I have been at the receiving end of both).

In most organizations that have a Board of Directors, executive management has to be approved by the board - this is especially true for outside hires.

In regulated industries, it might be a compliance issue as well - certain appointments have to go through a specific mandated process which is then audited.

For internal promotions - these fall into two main categories:

1. BCP/Succession Planning - in this scenario the incumbent usually nominates a person who is then approved by the concerned department. For executive management this would be the board, for those lower on the totem pole this is usually HR.
2. Direct Promotion - this is exactly what it sounds like, and can occur between departments as well. In this scenario, the position does not go through the formal hiring process; except maybe an interview with their new manager if its a department/business unit change.

I have not worked at a publisher but given the scrutiny and liability attached to the position, it is understandable that (even if its for audit or liability) there is an archaic process for appointments.